# is "I've never said that nor thought it" correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"I've never said that nor thought it"

I don't think so, but I don't know how I can say it.

Comment: It's both correct and clear, though it has a bit of an old-fashioned,high-society, Gone-with-the-Wind kind of feel to it.

Comment: In casual conversation (or even a heated argument), I'd personally phrase it along the lines or "I've never said that, *or even* thought it."

Comment: @DanBron: Me too. This is a higher-register construction; it used to be common in literature, but it went out of fashion over a century ago, except in parody and irony. Literature often put it in people's mouths, but literature rarely reported actual speech accurately until the 20th century -- and rarely enough even then. If you want to sound strange to most English speakers, this is a good way to talk.